# how do i get remote image filesize?

Tags: php

i am trying to get remote image file size.

but i am getting this error: 
"Warning: filesize(): stat failed for http://mfastore.com/_store/user_data/9fc8022_310/C/hydrangeas.jpg
unknown file size 
"

this is the code i am trying to get image size in  MB

```
    $res= formatFilebytes("http://mfastore.com/_store/user_data/9fc8022_310/C/hydrangeas.jpg","MB");
echo $res;

function formatFilebytes($file, $type)
{
switch($type){
case "KB":
$filesize = filesize($file) * .0009765625; // bytes to KB
break;
case "MB":
$filesize = (filesize($file) * .0009765625) * .0009765625; // bytes to MB
break;
case "GB":
$filesize = ((filesize($file) * .0009765625) * .0009765625) * .0009765625; // bytes to GB
break;
}
if($filesize <= 0){
return $filesize = 'unknown file size';}
else{return round($filesize, 2).' '.$type;}
}
```

help me please.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$image_header = get_headers("http://mfastore.com/_store/user_data/9fc8022_310/C/hydrangeas.jpg", true);
$size = $image_header["Content-Length"];
```

Comment: Worth noting that the remote server is not obligated to return the Content Length - and `$image_header["Content-Length"]` may not defined in that case.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution works for me...

```
 $url = 'http://mfastore.com/_store/user_data/9fc8022_310/C/hydrangeas.jpg';

echo getRemoteFilesize($url);

function getRemoteFilesize($url, $formatSize = true)
{
    $head = array_change_key_case(get_headers($url, 1));
    // content-length of download (in bytes), read from Content-Length: field
    $clen = isset($head['content-length']) ? $head['content-length'] : 0;

    // cannot retrieve file size, return "-1"
    if (!$clen) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (!$formatSize) {
        return $clen; // return size in bytes
    }

    $size = $clen;
    switch ($clen) {
        case $clen < 1024:
            $size = $clen .' B'; break;
        case $clen < 1048576:
            $size = round($clen / 1024, 2) .' KiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1073741824:
            $size = round($clen / 1048576, 2) . ' MiB'; break;
        case $clen < 1099511627776:
            $size = round($clen / 1073741824, 2) . ' GiB'; break;
    }

    return $size; // return formatted size
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this will help you and this an example:

```
$filesize = filesize($folder_url . $file) * .0009765625; // bytes to KB
```